# How to draw a bitmap via Graphics.DrawImage() without blinking

Tags: c#, optimization, graphics, bitmap

I am making a simple C# game. I tryed to use PictureBox as sprite, but it hasn't got transperency, so i had to use Graphics. The trouble is that image is blinking, when it's drawn too many times.
Here is the code:

```
public partial class GameWindow : Form
{
    Bitmap HeroIdle = Properties.Resources.Ава;
    int HeroX = 15;
    int HeroY = 15;
    public GameWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Painted(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(HeroIdle, new Point(HeroX, HeroY));
    }

    private void Key_IsDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs key)
    {
        if(key.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            HeroX += 4;
        }
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you turn on DoubleBuffered for the form?

Comment: @Taw, i tryed, but it didn't give me result.

Comment: @SOCIOPATH i do not use C# so I may be wrong but you are clearing and then drawing which is blinking by design. To stop blinking you can either turn on back-buffering but in such case you need to play with invalidate and update methods properly or use separate bitmap draw all there and when finished draw that on your picture box (the same as you own back-buffering) another option is do not use clear but fill rectangle areas not overlapping with the bitmap.